# @Url.Action() returns null from JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I want to create my url dynamically instead of hardcoding inside JQuery. I tried several ways(shown inside alert boxes in code snippet) but the address part of the url is always null. I get only the parameter part that i need in one of the alert boxes used for testing. Also, in my project i have Area for the controller. So that must be specified too.  The last alertbox returns the best i got in my attempt to create the url.Please take a look at my code and tell me why I dont get my url correctly. If you need anymore details, please let me know. Thank you.
Note: It works fine in localhost if I hard code the url inside the $.post(). But it breaks when deployed to Development environment. Thats why the url has to be created dynamically.

This is my html code relevent to this part.

```
     <td>
         <a href="#" alt="Set Private" id="publicImage@(photo.ID)" data-photoid="@photo.ID" class="view @(photo.IsPublic ? "" : "hide")" title="Set this photo to not public.">Public</a>
         <a href="#" alt="Set Public" id="privateImage@(photo.ID)" data-photoid="@photo.ID" class="noView @(photo.IsPublic ? "hide" : "")" title="Set this photo to public.">Private</a>
      </td>
```

This is my script. It is written directly inside the html page after the html code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[id*='publicImage']").click(function () {
            var pid = $(this).data("photoid");

            var url = @Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" }); 

            alert(@Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" }))//returns ""

            alert(@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" }))); //returns ""

            alert(@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" }))+'?id=' + pid + '&status=False'); // returns "NaN&status=False"

            alert('@Url.Action("status", "photos", new { Area = "account" })?id=' + $(this).data("photoid") + '&status=False'); // returns "?id=703548&status=False"

            $.post(
                url,//'/account/photos/' + id + "/status/False",
                function () {
                    $("#publicImage" + id).addClass("hide");
                    $("#privateImage" + id).removeClass("hide");
                }
            )
        });
```

This is my controller action method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{id}/status/{status}")]
    public virtual ActionResult Status(int id, bool status)
    {
        _photosClient.SetPublicStatus(id, status);
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Account.Photos.Index());
    }
```

Comment: You shoud use ActionLink with single quotes in javascript code like following '@Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" })'

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" })` returns a string.

So, you will need to quote it double quote or single quote. *For example,*

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" })";
```

Comment: I tried these and still got emplty string.                                                    alert( '@Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" })' )
alert( '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" }))' );                                                                                      The developer tool shows the value as this . 
alert('')
alert('');

Comment: It seems like you have routing issue. Could you remove `[Route("{id}/status/{status}")]` and try again? Then post the data inside body instead of Url.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just as a suggestion since you are getting the url in the variable `var url = @Url.Action("Status", "Photos", new { Area = "Account" });`  just check with the breakpoint what value you are getting and assign if it is not null to the alert like below:

```
alert(url);
```

And one morething i would like to address is that ,

As per your Note: It works fine in localhost if I hard code the url inside the $.post(). But it breaks when deployed to Development environment. Thats why the url has to be created dynamically.

For this note problem, you can put the url with the double dots `../status/photos`  , i had this problem and solved it like this.

useful link:https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/186719

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Thank everyone. It was a routing issue. When i added [Route("status")] above the controller method, i got the correct url instead of null.

Comment: great and enjoy..:)